# Downside to Mortising Jigs against Festool DOMINO?

Tags: joinery

There are a number of Chinese mortising jigs on the market which work by mounting a trim router,

- [GANWEI 2-In-1 Slotting Wood Trimming Machine Holder - Banggood Tool Sets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4rQ3Jnbk9I)
- [Tianli Mortising Jig](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Zn7ZDscblg)

Given this model of mortising jig, is there any disadvantage to this over a Festool DOMINO? I don't see any professional woodworking channels using non-DOMINO mortising jigs, but it's not clear why? **Other than the cost saving, is there any benefit of these jigs when compared to the Festool DOMINO? Are there any disadvantages?**

Comment: IF you have a question, include an image of the jig with a specific question about its use.  It is not appropriate to ask for opinions here.  Learn more [here](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: This is going to be a like a lot of things, with people of different levels making decisions that make sense to them. Pros make decisions based on what makes economic sense for them and their pluses/minuses aren't going to necessarily translate downwards (even to the more dedicated and experienced amateurs, as well as many semi-pros). The [exorbitant] cost of the Domino alone is enough to deter some pros, so obviously it will easily put off the majority of non-pros!

Comment: What you're wondering about could easily be expanded to a more general query, why floating tenons joinery and not dowels, since the actual joinery item is cheaper (and will *always* be cheaper), the equipment is cheaper (and then some!), the process is nearly as fast in practice, and last but by no means least dowels have a proven track record that shows they are by no means the lesser option. In case you don't know, numerous tests measure dowel joints as the strongest, even better than real M&T joints. And where through-dowels are possible you can go even further and get a dovetail-like lock.

Comment: I've seen _many_ woodworkers showing how to build your own domino-cutting jig, including some who are obviously professionals and have started their YT channel as an extra income stream. Many even compare their jigs to the "official" Festool Domino cutter that they own and use and have liked their own version more.

Answer (score 3):

> Other than the cost saving, is there any benefit of these jigs when compared to the Festool DOMINO? Are there any disadvantages?

There are lots of differences. One is a power tool that's part of an integrated system and which includes motor, cutter, a fence that's adjustable to different angles, tools, and a well-designed container to hold everything. The other is a jig.

One is a Festool product, so you can expect to pay a premium price for a tool that works extremely well and plays nicely with other Festool products, notably their line of excellent dust extractors, and you can expect a high level of support if you ever have a problem. The other is sold on Ebay.

I don't own a Domino or either of the jigs you linked to, so I can't say first-hand how the mortises they produce compare. My expectation is that the Festool will work very well, and the quality you get from the jigs will depend in large part on the router and bit that you use with them. One obvious difference in operation is that the Domino continually moves the bit back and forth as you make the cut; the jigs require the user to move the tool. It's hard to tell whether the resulting mortises will vary significantly, but using the Domino looks to be a bit quicker and more convenient.

Price is obviously a huge advantage for the jigs. At around $195, they cost about %20 of what the cheapest Domino system does. Although you still have to supply the router and bit, many woodworkers may already have those on hand. At that price, many hobbyists will be happy to sacrifice a bit of convenience.

Comment: This is a good write up, but when you say "angles" in "angles, tools, and a well-designed container" do you mean to say that the FESTOOL has the ability to do different angles then jig? If so could you explain a bit about that functionality? What kind of angles?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Just take a look at [the fence on the Domino](https://festoolcdn.azureedge.net/productmedia/Images/jpg_large/9561c3c2-2589-11e5-80cf-005056b31774_1600_1066.jpg) -- it works like the fence on a biscuit joiner. You can set it to various angles so that you can make mortises along edges that have angles other than 90°. As far as I can tell, and from what the reviewer in the second video says explicitly, you can't do that with the jig in question, at least not without rigging up some additional support.

Comment: Excellent summary Caleb! I would take minor issue re. Festool's level of support; in addition to varying more by country than one might hope for [it isn't all roses and kittens](https://www.lumberjocks.com/threads/disappointment-with-festool-complete-failure-with-minimal-use.323707/) ^_^

Comment: Agree that this is a solid answer. Would note (and this is coming from someone who *isn't* a festool fan) that the resale value of festool is extremely high.